# REACT JS, How To Fetch Data From an API in child components

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React js, and I am trying to fetch [API](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list) data with "map function" in child component, which is related to it's parent component with React-Router. Before creating fetch method I have tested communication between those 2 components and it works. But after clicking in "Router Link", that goes to child component without changes, except the text I put for testing. Console.log executes  "undefined" for looping with "map function". I will ge grateful for any help.

Here is the parent component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CategoryCard from "./CategoryCard";
import "./styles.css";

export default () => {
const [data, setData] = useState("");

const fetchData = () => {
  fetch("https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => setData(data.meals))
  .catch(error => console.log("error"))
}


useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [])


const loopedComponents =data && data.map((element, index)=>(
  <CategoryCard
    key={index}
    category = {element.strCategory}
  />
))
console.log(data)


  return (
      <div>     
        <CategoryCard category = {loopedComponents} />
      </div>
  );
};
```

child component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default ({category}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Card starts here</h3>
      <div>
      {category}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and grand component, where I use Router

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, NavLink, useParams  } from "react-router-dom";
import RecipeTopics from "./RecipeTopics";
import CategorieList from "./CategorieList";
import "./styles.css";


function HOME() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Routers() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className = "Routers">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/" activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "black"
            }}>
              HOME
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/Category" activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "red"
            }}>
              CATEGORY
            </NavLink>
          </li>

          <li>
            <NavLink to="/Ingredients" activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "red"
            }}>
              INGREDIENTS
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/AddRecipe" activeStyle={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              color: "red"
            }}>
              ADD RECIPE
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <HOME />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/Category">
              <CategorieList />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/Ingredients">
              <Ingredients />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/AddRecipe">
              <AddRecipe />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: `.then(result => setData(data.meals))` should probably be `.then(result => setData(result.meals))`. I don't see where else the `data` object should be coming from

Comment: thanks a lot, it works

Comment: @patman yes, the problem was really there